# Wifi shuts off after inactivity

Tags: wireless, 18.04, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Optiplex 745 with a USB Realtek wifi antenna (RTL8188SU). Whenever I leave my computer downloading larger files (e.g. distribution ISO images) and I come back to the computer I find the wifi has dropped connection in mid-download. I restart network manager to no avail. What's more is that after the connection has dropped I'm no longer able to see my wireless access point under "select a network". The only solution that works is rebooting the computer, after which everything goes back to normal. Until I start downloading files again.

I've looked into possible solutions such as turning off power management, but when I run iwconfig it states that power management is off.

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"Wifiap"  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point:   
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0


wlan0    usb-devices | awk '/8171/' RS=
    T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
    D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
    P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8171 Rev=02.00
    S:  Manufacturer=Manufacturer Realtek 
    S:  Product=RTL8188S WLAN Adapter 
    S:  SerialNumber=
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
    I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=r8712u
```

---

UPDATE: I tried sudo opening Nautilus thinking that maybe I could just delete my router from the /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections folder as a work around to get my wireless adapter to recognize the router again, but that didn't work.

FYI, I am a Linux novice. I know enough to be dangerous, but not nearly enough to be useful/competent. Therefore, I'm still at a loss for what I can do to prevent this from happening.

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

UPDATE 2: I wasn't able to fix the issue for the wireless adapter, but I did seem to find a solution in buying a new wireless adapter, the Panda Wireless PAU06, which I'd read is Linux compatible. So far, with the new adapter, I've downloaded the CentOS Everything ISO image (nearly 9 GB size file) via torrent and direct download from a couple different mirrors. The problem hasn't reoccurred either way.

Considering the old adapter works fine with Windows I'm going to assume it's not something physically wrong with the adapter itself but a software issue. The only thing that I can think of that could be the issue is that "retry" is set to "off" on the old adapter, as you can see in the info I posted above, whereas on the new adapter it's set to "Retry short  long limit:2". I don't know why the old adapter would be set to "off", but maybe that was/is the culprit. I will try to play around with the old adapter soon to see if setting the retry limit fixes the problem and give another update then.

Comment: Tried to set retry limit and it gave back this error: 

Error for wireless request "Set Retry Limit" (8B28) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Function not implemented.

Btw, I omitted the name of the wireless device above. enp3s0 isn't the wireless device.

Comment: when you have your wifi issue, you can do `sudo service network-manager restart` instead of restarting totally the computer, it's temporary but less embarrassing than what you re doing after your downloading

Comment: @damadam Yeah, I've run that command numerous times in terminal. As I said in the original question, restarting network manager does no good. It doesn't even show my router in the list of available networks after I've restarted the network manager. For some reason downloading large files borks the wireless adapter. I can leave the computer for hours and come back to it and my wifi is fine, but when I start downloading large files: borked wifi.